# Понятие абстрактного типа данных

Tags: java, типы-данных, типы, типизация, теория-типов

К сожалению, не смог найти на просторах глобальной сети подходящего для меня объяснения этого понятия. Когда заходит речь об абстрактных типах данных (АТД), то многие путают их с абстрактными классами (речь идёт о программистах из сообщества языка программирования Java), что совершенно не одно и то же. Для меня крайне важно понимать такие базовые понятия, как АТД, так как они являются фундаментальными и из них вытекают такие ключевые концепции ООП, как класс. Ведь если начать разбираться, то любой класс в Java является абстрактным типом данных, поставляемым с полной или частичной реализацией.

Из того, что мне удалось понять, под АТД подразумевается некоторое абстрактное множество данных и допустимых операций на них. Но это чересчур размытая формулировка, которая не даёт полного представления о данном понятии. Если следовать ей, то можно приравнять АТД к интерфейсам (хоть интерфейс и является в общем случае АТД, но это, отнюдь, не взаимозаменяемые понятия).

В общем, если можно, то объясните что же это такое на каких-нибудь относительно простеньких примерах. Буду всем крайне благодарен!

Comment: А чем из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) определение не подходит?

Comment: Я не могу сказать, что оно мне не подходит. Просто я не очень его понимаю, как бы странно это не звучало. Может быть это только мне кажется мудрёным, но я бы как-то это всё перефразировал. Хотелось бы получить объяснение на простом русском языке, если это возможно.

Comment: И да, если бы мне всё было изначально понятно, то я бы не стал беспокоить участников многоуважаемого сообщества Stack Overflow. Пользоваться поиском я умею. Прежде чем написать, я просмотрел где-то с десяток сайтов, где нашёл фактически одно и то же определение, которое не пролило свет на мой вопрос. Как-то так. Заранее прошу прощения, если кому-то мой вопрос показался не совсем корректным.

Comment: _Если следовать ей, то можно приравнять АТД к интерфейсам_ - на самом деле нельзя, так как интерфейсы описывают только операции, но не данные.

Comment: А как же статические финализированные переменные, которые имеют место быть в интерфейсах? Это разве не данные?

Comment: неа, как раз потому, что они статические

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как правильно охарактеризовать АТД? Это обобщение для классов и интерфейсов?

Comment: Ну, вики же четко это описывает: Абстра́ктный тип да́нных (АТД) — это математическая модель для типов данных, где тип данных определяется поведением (семантикой) с точки зрения пользователя данных, а именно в терминах возможных значений, возможных операций над данными этого типа и поведения этих операций.

Comment: Абстрактные классы и интерфейсы могут быть АТД, если они описаны в соответствии с вышеописанным определением. Однако, если пихать в интерфейсы константы и прочий беспредел, тогда, то что предназначено для описания АТД - размывается и перестает им быть. Думаю, интерфейсы в коллекциях близки к АТД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абстрактный тип данных это скорее математическое и где-то даже философское понятие.

Есть такая историческая байка

---

*Однажды ученики древнегреческого философа Сократа завели диспут на тему что такое человек, Сократ выслушав все мнения учеников высказал свою знаменитую сентенцию:*

> Человек - это птица на двух ногах без перьев

*Один из учеников, не будь дураком, желая посрамить философа, тут же притащил ощипанную курицу, Сократ презрительно осмотрев курицу выдал:*

> забыл добавить, с плоскими ногтями

---

К чему это я. К тому что в данном случае философ был прав, поскольку он давал определение понятию через его свойства/операции. АТД и есть в данном случае понятие определяемое через его операции - это некая *модель*.

Например, что такое птицы - птицы это некие существа, которые могут летать. В смысле программирования, если множество выполняет операцию `летать` - значит это птица, ну или в смысле Java:

```
class Птица implements Летающее {
}
```

С точки зрения программирования абстрактный класс является реализацией АТД (одной из реализаций).

**Например**

АТД - стек. Стек это модель данных, в котором элементы, организованы по принципу LIFO, то есть данные можно или вытащить верхний или протолкнуть следующий.

В программировании `Stack` абстрактный класс с двумя методами `push()/pop()`